# I want to send a file from a customer to a server and then I want to resend it to the customer

Tags: file, sockets

I'm trying to make a chat between one server and many customers using sockets but I want to send files, Could someone tell me please how can I send a file from a customer to a server and resend it to the customers???

Answer (score 0):

Just read and write the bytes. There's nothing different about sending files as against sending anything else, except maybe you need to send the name and possibly the length as well.